# Prisma: Error validating - "You must specify the same number of fields in fields and references"

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I know this is kind of not realistic but just testing and confused about solution:
I'm encountering an error in my Prisma schema, and I'm seeking assistance. Here's my simplified schema:

prisma

```
model User {
email     String   @unique
createdAt DateTime @default(now())
firstName String
lastName  String
posts     Post[]
@@id([firstName, lastName], name: "fullName")
}

model Post {
id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
title      String
userId     String?
user       User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [firstName, lastName], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Prisma: Error validating - "You must specify the same number of fields in fields and references"

The error I'm facing is "You must specify the same number of fields in fields and references." I understand that this is related to the @relation directive, but I'm having trouble resolving it.

I've tried adjusting the fields and references arrays, but the issue persists. Could someone provide guidance on how to correctly set up this relationship in Prisma?

Thank you!

At Post @relation --> I tried to change several option such as: references: [fullName] ; references: [id] but it throws another error: Error validating: The argument `references` must refer only to existing fields in the related model User. The following fields do not exist in the related model: id

I just try to use in User --> using @@id instead of using id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement()) just for testing purpose only.

---

Oh, I found something and hope this make sense:
`name` only works when we are using to query eg:

```
const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    fullName: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    },
  },
});
```

but it is not working when we use to @relation between table.
Back to this case, to use @@id to relation --> we have to create both key-value in both table like below:

```
model User {
  firstName String
  lastName  String
  profile   Profile?

  @@id([firstName, lastName], name: "fullName")
}

model Profile {
  id            Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  user          User   @relation(fields: [userFirstName, userLastName], references: [firstName, lastName])
  userFirstName String
  userLastName  String

  @@unique([userFirstName, userLastName])
}
```

Comment: What is `userId` supposed to be matching in `User`?

Comment: this can be change to `userFullName` for to be clear when I want to match with `name` in `@@id`. But this way is not working as I edited above.